# canceling Synchronous multipart request

Tags: loopj

I need to send multipart post request from AsyncTask using loopj, so I'm forced to use SyncHttpClient.

Reading the source code comments, I'm learning that a Request Handle returned from the post method of synchronous request cannot be used to cancel the request because it is already complete by the time this returns (which makes sense). Looks like a catch 22 though.

Is there another way to cancel a currently running Synchronous request?
Is it possible to use SyncHttpClient.cancelAllRequests(true); from the UI thread?
Well, SyncHttpClient.cancelAllRequests(true) from the UI thread does not work. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you can use AsyncHttpRequest if you want to be able to cancel the running request. It doesn't matter if you are running your asynchronous http request from another thread or even an AsyncTask, you just have to make sure that the AsyncHttpRequest is called on the main thread. You can do this easily by forcing it into the main thread using

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
// run your AsyncHttpRequest in here. 
// Since it is called from the main thread it will run asynchronously
// and therefore it can be cancelled easily by calling client.cancelAllRequests(true) 
  }
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```